# Bind to NSTreeController selectionIndexPaths

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, bind, nstreecontroller

I want to bind to a NSTreeController's selectionIndexPaths programatically by doing the following (so that I can get a string a selection and display in a text view)

> [activePDFView bind:@"name"
>   toObject:treeController
>   withKeyPath:@"selectionIndexPaths.nodeName"
>   options:options];

The tree controller is bound to a NSMutableArray that contains objects with the "nodeName" property. The object inside the NSMutableArray is KVC compliant for the property "nodeName" since I've implemented the proper accessors.

When I compile, I get the following message

> '[<__NSArray0 0x1001698d0>
>   addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:]
>   is not supported. Key path: nodeName'

I am not quite sure but is my binding correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want to bind to is not `selectionIndexPaths`, but instead the `selection` binding. The `selectionIndexPaths` binding will return an array of `NSIndexPath` objects, which is typically only used when binding an outline/browser view's selection to the tree controller.  `selection` actually returns a proxy object which can represent either a single or multiple selection, and passes through any KVC requests to the underlying selected object(s). It's defined in `NSObjectController`, which is a superclass of `NSTreeController`. In your case, you would want:

```
[activePDFView bind:@"name" toObject:treeController withKeyPath:@"selection.nodeName" options:options];
```